# Get the value from a particular column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm trying to alert message on click each column. I have a table in which three row and four column, now I want alert message with next column value on third column click of each table. I have tried this but all column get value not a particular column. my problem is this is invoke in every column click but I want alert message only when third column click of each row.

HTML

```
<table id='myTable'>
<tr><td>R1C1</td><td>R1C2</td><td>R1C3</td><td>R1C4</td></tr>
<tr><td>R2C1</td><td>R2C2</td><td>R2C3</td><td>R2C4</td></tr>
<tr><td>R3C1</td><td>R3C2</td><td>R3C3</td><td>R3C4</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$("#myTable tr").bind("click", function () {
     alert($(this).children("td").eq(3).html());
});
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/zEkeg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('table#myTable tr td:nth-child(3)').on('click', function() {
            alert($(this).next().html());
        });
```

Check [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/zEkeg/2/)

Answer (score 3):

please try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myTable tr').each(function (Mindex, Mval) {
                $(Mval).find('td:eq(2)').click(function () {
                    alert($(Mval).find('td:eq(3)').html());
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myTable tr td:nth-child(3)").click(function () {
     alert($(this).next().html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('#myTable').children('tr').children('td').eq(3).on('click', function() {
     alert($(this).next().html());
 });
```

The above function makes sure that you are calling the direct children elements but not any nested other same elements. Solves future regressions.

Answer (score 1):

If your table is going to stay the same size there are answers that already work. If your table is going to grow I would recommend doing some event delegation. It will dramatically speed up the page if there are going to be a large number of event listeners.

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td:nth-child(3)', function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwPjy/), and this [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

below code will find and set the desired column value

```
$('#myTable tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
       // console.log($('td:eq(3)', $(this)).html());
        alert($('td:eq(3)', $(this)).html());
        $('#myTable').find('tr:gt(0)').find('td:eq(3)').html("hello");
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var thirdEle = $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(3)");
thirdEle.bind("click", function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```